# Why msync() doesn't change the st_mtime of file

Tags: linux, mmap

I have a question when I use msync. Thank you very much for your help!

In brief, I mmap file A, and modify it, and the msync, but the st_mtime doesn't change. even munmap file A and exit the process, the st_mtime is also unchanged.

The following is the code.

```
int main() {
    const char *file_name = "txt";
    int ret = -1;
    int fd = open(file_name, O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("FATAL, Fail to open file[%s]\n", file_name);
        return -1;
    }
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fd, &st);
    void * buffer = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, 
                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                    MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (MAP_FAILED == buffer) {
        printf("FATAL, Fail to mmap, file[%s], size[%d]\n",
            file_name, st.st_size);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("m_time[%d]\n", st.st_mtime);
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++) {
        int *ptr = (int *)buffer;
        printf("%d\n", *ptr);
        *ptr += 1;
        sleep(1);
        ret = msync(buffer, st.st_size, MS_ASYNC);
        if (0 != ret) {
            printf("FATAL, Fail to msync, file[%s], size[%d]\n",
                file_name, st.st_size);
            return -1;
        }
        fstat(fd, &st);
        printf("m_time[%d]\n", st.st_mtime);
    }
    ret = munmap(buffer, st.st_size);
    if (0 != ret) {
        printf("FATAL, Fail to munmap, file[%s], size[%d]\n",
            file_name, st.st_size);
        return -1;
    }
    fstat(fd, &st);
    printf("m_time[%d]\n", st.st_mtime);
    fsync(fd);
    fstat(fd, &st);
    printf("m_time[%d]\n", st.st_mtime);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant excerpt of the `mmap` manpage is:

> The st_ctime and st_mtime field for a file mapped with **PROT_WRITE** and **MAP_SHARED** will be updated after a write to the mapped region, and before a subsequent **msync**(2) with the **MS_SYNC** or **MS_ASYNC** flag, if one occurs.

That means that, in your program, `st_mtime` might be updated anytime between the line which reads

```
*ptr += 1`
```

and and the line which reads

```
ret = msync(buffer, st.st_size, MS_ASYNC);
```

Your `sleep(1)` is in between those lines, which means that by the time the sleep occurs, the `st_mtime` might have already been modified. So when you `fstat` the file a second time, you might be getting the same value as when you statted it the first time, just because not enough time has elapsed.

Try putting your `sleep(1)` before the `*ptr += 1`. This should guarantee that at least one second elapses between the original `fstat` and the update to the `st_mtime`.

Comment: Thank for your replay, I put sleep(1) before *ptr += 1, but the st_mtime is also unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fix is on the way.

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1549524/focus=55700